# Regex to Extract Arabic text Using Java

Tags: java, regex, twitter, arabic, twitter4j

I want to extract only Arabic text from a file that contains many non-Arabic texts and elements e.g (English, emojie, numbers ..etc), using Regex, I found many tutorials here and they work! but the problem is I get the letters attached for Ex: 
`String text = "123 اهلين و سهلين"`
after applying regex

`output:
"اهلينوسهلين"`

`The output I want:
"اهلين و سهلين"`

I tried so many ways to solve this including:
`"\\p{InArabic}+(?:\\s+\\p{InArabic}+)*"`
`"(?:[\\u0600-\\u06FF]+(?:\\s+[\\u0600-\\u06FF]+)*)"`
`"^[\\p\\{Arabic\\}\\s]+$"`
But I was unable to get the results that I need even though others, based on their questions, were able to find the same output structure as I need using these regex.

My code:

```
    String regex = "\\p{InArabic}+";
    String outString;
    String cleaned = "";
    Scanner in = new Scanner(new FileReader(path+"tweets.txt"));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    while(in.hasNext()) {
        sb.append(in.next());
    }
    in.close();
    outString = sb.toString();
    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE | 
    Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS);
    final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(outString);
    while (matcher.find()) {
       cleaned = cleaned +" "+ matcher.group();
    }
```

I ran my code on another text file and it worked it showed the right output in the right format, so I think the problem is with the text file I'm trying to run the code on, which is retrieved tweets using twitter4j so perhaps there's a problem with that?

Comment: I removed from the question, it was a comment in the code, I still get the same results

Comment: Since you add a space between the previous and the new match, there must be a space in the `cleaned` variable, you just do not "see" it perhaps. Just FYI: `Pattern.MULTILINE` can be removed from the code.

Answer (score 1):

This outputs exactly the desired text in your question:

```
text.replaceAll("[^\\p{InARABIC} ]", "").trim()
```

This uses the *negative* character POSIX class for Arabic letters, and adds a call to `trim()`.

If you absolutely must use a single regex (ie no call to `trim()`):

```
text.replaceAll("^[\\P{InARABIC}\\d ]*|[\\P{InARABIC} ]*$", "")
```

---

This code:

```
System.out.println(" اهلين و سهلين 123".replaceAll("[^\\p{InARABIC} ]", "").trim()
```

Outputs:

```
اهلين و سهلين
```

Comment: I don't want the letters attached, I want them in the right format "اهلين و سهلين"

Comment: What "letters" exactly? What version of java are you using?

Comment: I'm using Java 8, I mean the end letters of the words

Comment: @FXTIMX your question seems to says you want the output to be `اهلينوسهلين`. Please post exactly the output you want.

Comment: I don't suppose you are not assigning the return value from `replaceAll()` to a variable, ie `text = text.replaceAll("\\P{InARABIC};`. Just calling `text.replaceAll("\\P{InARABIC}` does nothing.

Comment: @Bohemian By "letters attached" the OP means the words must not be joined up, i.e. all space characters must be preserved, not just the Arabic text.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this regex `[^\u0600-\u06FF\\s]+` which mean replace non Arabic character or space with empty :

```
String text = "123 اهلين و سهلين, Welcome, Bienvenue, Hola";
text = text.replaceAll("[^\u0600-\u06FF\\s]+", "");
```

Output

```
اهلين و سهلين
```

You can also use `trim()` in the end to remove space in the start and in the end :

```
text = text.replaceAll("[^\u0600-\u06FF\\s]+", "").trim();
```

---

#### Code demo

Comment: I still get the same attached letters :(  "اهلينوسهلين"

Comment: I've seen many demos on many answers including yours and they all get the correct format but when I run the code I still get the attached letters, I use Java 8 could that have anything to do with it?

Comment: i use it too, can you tell me which IDE you are using?

Comment: I use NetBeans 8.2

Comment: either me i use netbeans 8.2 ;) i think it is a problem of encoding check your IDE encoding please

Comment: can you please elaborate more? Like I checked my encoding and it's UTF-8, should I change it to UTF-16 ?

Comment: @FXTIMX are you sure that there are not a special characters in your file between the words ?

Answer (score 0):

```java
public class HelloWorld
{

     public static void main(String []args)
     {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        System.out.println (containsArabicLetters("بسيب سيبيس سيبسيبسي سشسشس"));
     }

     public static boolean containsArabicLetters(String text)
     {
        
        char[] ch1 = text.replaceAll(" ", "").toCharArray();
        
        for (char c:ch1)
        {
            if (c >= 0x600 && c <= 0x6ff)
                continue;
            if (c >= 0x750 && c <= 0x77f)
                continue;
            if (c >= 0xfb50 && c <= 0xfc3f)
                continue;
            if (c >= 0xfe70 && c <= 0xfefc)
                continue;
            else
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: First, the post has formatting issues. Second, this answer does not explain why it works, how can one learn from it?